# How do I control events (like buttons) in jQuery Plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm new to jQuery Plugins.

Problem: If I want to call my plugin severeal times, controls-event-listeners (like buttons) from previous instances are called too.

In my case, I have a single button (called btnDone in the sample below), which must be used for all instances.

How can I in the code below, make sure only the right instance-event is called.

[Fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/MojoDK/qhj66L5y/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<ol>
    <li>Click button 1.</li>
    <li>Click done</li>
    <li>Click button 2</li>
    <li>Click done - here I want only event for '2' to show, but event for '1' is called too ... how do I fix this?</li>
</ol>

<button id='btn1'>1</button>
<button id='btn2'>2</button>

<button id='btnDone' style='display:none'>Done</button>

<div id='divConsol'></div>
```

**Script:**

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $.findCustomerDialog = function (options) {

        var defaultOptions = {          
            title: '',
        };

        var opts = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);
        $("#btnDone").show();
        $("#btnDone").click(function() {  
            $("#divConsol").append("<div>" + opts.title + "</div>");
            $("#btnDone").hide();
        });

    };

})(jQuery)


$(document).ready(function ($) {

    $("#btn1").click(function (e) { 
        $("#divConsol").append("<div>-----------------------</div>");
        $.findCustomerDialog({
            title: '1',
        });
    });

    $("#btn2").click(function (e) { 
        $("#divConsol").append("<div>-----------------------</div>");
        $.findCustomerDialog({
            title: '2',
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice catch! Give an `.off("click")` to clear the previous event binding and then use the one again. This will fix:

```
$("#btnDone").off("click").click(function() {  
    $("#divConsol").append("<div>" + opts.title + "</div>");
    $("#btnDone").hide();
});
```

You already have a handler for `.click()` which is called twice. Remove the old one.

**Snippet:**

```js
(function ($) {
  'use strict';
  $.findCustomerDialog = function (options) {
    var defaultOptions = {   
      title: '',
    };
    var opts = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);
    $("#btnDone").show();
    $("#btnDone").off("click").click(function() {  
      $("#divConsol").append("<div>" + opts.title + "</div>");
      $("#btnDone").hide();
    });
  };
})(jQuery)

$(document).ready(function ($) {
  $("#btn1").click(function (e) { 
    $("#divConsol").append("<div>-----------------------</div>");
    $.findCustomerDialog({
      title: '1',
    });
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function (e) { 
    $("#divConsol").append("<div>-----------------------</div>");
    $.findCustomerDialog({
      title: '2',
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: Segoe UI;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>Click button 1.</li>
  <li>Click done</li>
  <li>Click button 2</li>
  <li>Click done - here I want only event for '2' to show, but event for '1' is called too ... how do I fix this?</li>
</ol>

<button id='btn1'>1</button>
<button id='btn2'>2</button>

<button id='btnDone' style='display:none'>Done</button>

<div id='divConsol'></div>
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/qhj66L5y/2/**

Answer (score 0):

`off` is not a solid fix. You need to pass an element or a selector to the plugin so it knows which element to hook click for and so also it can work with a selector, i.e. :`findCustomerDialog($(".someClass"))` :

http://jsfiddle.net/qhj66L5y/3/

pass id to the function, can also use a selector, this is just a sample, not a full working demo:

Pass some indicator to tell the plugin which element to work with, 1 is just a sample but it can be a jQuery selector or an element itself, i.e.:

```
$.findCustomerDialog($("#btn1"), {
        title: '1',
});
```

or

```
$.findCustomerDialog($(".btns"), {
        title: '1',
});
```

or simple sample:

```
$.findCustomerDialog(1, {
        title: '1',
});
```

plugin knows which element to bind events for:

```
$("#btnDone" + id).show();
    $("#btnDone" + id).click(function() {  
        $("#divConsol").append("<div>" + opts.title + "</div>");
        $("#btnDone" + id).hide();
});
```

html, probably better if these buttons are created by the plugin:

```
<button id='btnDone1' style='display:none'>Done</button>
<button id='btnDone2' style='display:none'>Done</button>
```